# popover bootstrap not display on all pages although i put it on layout page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5, razor-pages

I work on asp.net razor pages . I face issue I can't display popovers content  on all pages of web applications

it working and display on some pages and some pages not working

popovers exist on layout page and all pages inherit from it

so my question why popovers not working on some pages and working on another page

I need to know why it not working

my layout page as below so

content `This is the popover content.` not show on on some pages so why and how to solve this issue please

```
DashboardLyout

<a  data-toggle="popover"  title="ahmed salah"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Img/imgprofile.png")" alt="ImageProfile" /></a>

@RenderBody()
                        <script>

                            $(function () {
                                // Enables popover
                                $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({ content: "This is the popover content."});
                            });
                        </script>
```

sample page from inherit from `DashboardLayout` page

```
@page "/AddBranch"
@model UC.ADC.Host.Pages.Branch.AddBranchModel
@{
    Layout = "DashboardLayout";
}
```

**why popovers working on some pages and display content and other pages not display content popovers**

Comment: Do you mean you create your own Layout page, Then some pages use this layout page can show `This is the popover content.` successfully but some pages use this layout page can't?

Comment: Have you checked the Console in browser to see if there is any error in the pages? I I suspect that the pages that don't load content successfully are because jquery library is not loaded or is not loaded earlier than `<script>$(function () {}.....</script>`.

Comment: Yes exactly working on some page and some pages not so tell me what i do to check issue

Comment: just press f12 in browser and check the Console.

Comment: In BS 5, the  attribute is `data-bs-toggle` not `data-toggle`

Comment: please you mean console.log(content)

Comment: No, please refer to [link](https://documentation.concretecms.org/tutorials/how-open-browser-console-view-errors).

Comment: ok after check console what i do because i don't see any error message on console so what you advice me to solve issue

Comment: Sorry, It's hard to find the solution just according to this , could you provide your whole project?